# Hide contour rectangle of sprite

Tags: c#, .net, xna, pipeline, monogame

How can I hide the contour of my sprite?

I tried to change in Pipeline

```
"ColorKeyColor" :- 00FFFFFF (RGBA : 255, 255, 255, 0) -00000000  (RGBA : 0,0 ,0 ,0)

"ColorKeyEnabled" : True or False

"PremultiplyAlpha" : True or False
```

I tried all possibilities because I don't understand the specifics of `PremultiplyAlpha` and the others, even after reading the documentation.

Some others have had the same problem which they can't solve : http://community.monogame.net/t/texture-alpha/

**Edit:** I partially understand what `PremultipliedAlpha` utility is and I understand it's not my problem, but I tried to change this value because I was desperate.

Comment: What do you mean by "Hide contour"? Do you want to mask a color so it is invisible?

Comment: I can't put a image because i'm new, but that means the background of my image.

Comment: You could add a link to an image that is similar.

Comment: Improved the quality of the language. Question is fine, just needed some minor improvements to increase readability and get rid of unnecessary 'fluff'. Could do with further explanation around the exact problem perhaps with screenshots, but as I don't understand the subject matter I've left it alone for now

Comment: I put language on "Tags", if you can see its that : c# , .net, xna monogame.

Comment: I find solution at my problem but in french, i put it here if someone speak french are same problems in the future : 
http://sainte-croix.forumgratuit.org/t435-gimp-2-8-fond-transparent

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see what your problem is. You seem to want to get rid of the background. Well, why don't you do it outside of your code in the Texture in a tool like Gimp or Paint.Net (or Photoshop, if you own it).

You can set one or multiple colors to be transparent in a texture, by comparing every pixel and set its alpha value to 0 when the color matches. But this is not very useful, since you do not have a way to tell your game what color you want to use besides using a separate file.